Regarding the processing of the model after the conclusion of the clock animation
The animation is over, and the model will disappear or loop, but I want to achieve real-time vehicle trajectory playback. The animation playback is not continuous, and there may be delays. Therefore, during the waiting time for data, I want the model to still be displayed on the map. I don't understand why the model needs to disappear when the animation ends.
const timeStepInSeconds = 30;
const totalSeconds = timeStepInSeconds * (flightData.length - 1);
const start = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601("2020-03-09T23:10:00Z");
const stop = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601("2020-03-09T24:10:10Z");
// Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(
//   start,
//   totalSeconds,
//   new Cesium.JulianDate()
// );
viewer.clock.startTime = start.clone();
viewer.clock.stopTime = stop.clone();
viewer.clock.currentTime = start.clone();
viewer.timeline.zoomTo(start, stop);
// Speed up the playback speed 50x.
viewer.clock.multiplier = 1;
// Start playing the scene.
viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = true;
viewer.clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.CLAMPED;
// The SampledPositionedProperty stores the position and timestamp for each sample along the radar sample series.
const positionProperty = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();
for (let i = 0; i < flightData.length; i++) {
  const dataPoint = flightData[i];
  const time = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601(dataPoint.time);
  const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
    dataPoint.longitude,
    dataPoint.latitude,
    dataPoint.height
  );

  positionProperty.addSample(time, position);
  viewer.entities.add({
    description: `Location: (${dataPoint.longitude}, ${dataPoint.latitude},     ${dataPoint.height})`,
    position: position,
    point: { pixelSize: 10, color: Cesium.Color.BLUE },
  });
}

